# Native Code coverage with android soong build system

Tags: android, code-coverage, android-source, gcov, android-soong

I'm trying to generate code coverage report for my native components with AOSP source code using soong build system.

I have extended aosp vhal but unit test cases are same as in below link.
http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/hardware/interfaces/automotive/vehicle/2.0/default/tests/

Tried adding below to cc_test, cc_binary in Android.bp

```
native_coverage : true,

    cflags: [
         "-g",
         "-O0",
         "-fprofile-arcs",
         "-ftest-coverage",
    ],

     ldflags : [
        "-fprofile-arcs",
        "-ftest-coverage",
    ],
```

Native binary **unit-tests-coverage** is generated in out/target/product but I can't find **gcno** intermediates for this.

Running below command gives me *.gcda files for each test files.

```
adb shell \
    GCOV_PREFIX=/data/local/tmp \
    GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP=`echo $ANDROID_BUILD_TOP | grep -o / | wc -l` \
    /data/local/tmp/unit-tests-coverage
```

I have tried below links but not sure how to proceed :(

http://logan.tw/posts/2015/04/28/check-code-coverage-with-clang-and-lcov/
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic.git/+/master-soong
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/581341d%5E%21/
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/e2fsprogs/+/fedfb27%5E%21/
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/scripts/acov#23
http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/bionic/README.md#293

I'm not sure if google's vts framework can be used here to generate native code coverage.
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-vts-8/#6

"**gcnodir**" is generated but not sure how to make use of it.
/coverage/data/nativetest64/vehicle-unit-tests-coverage/unit-tests-coverage.gcnodir

Comment: I'm looking for a solution too, any update?

Comment: "gcnodir" is actually a zip file and you can unzip it then get .gcno files. but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: check my answer@Ted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting answer to my question for other users on SO.

Install coverage tool :

1. `sudo apt-get install lcov` (This should install lcov-1.12)
2. `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.6` (Clang generates .gcno approximately equal to gcc 4.2 that aren't compatible 
   with gcov-4.8. Installing gcc-4.6 to get gcov-4.6 and invoking lcov with '--gcov-tool /usr/bin/gcov-4.6')
3. Download LLVM 3.8 for llvm-cov to work : http://releases.llvm.org/download.html

All native unit test cases i.e instrumented binary needs to be executed on target. To build and emit clang's instrumentation based profiling. Example: http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/hardware/interfaces/automotive/vehicle/2.0/default/Android.bp#82 (Renamed to vehicle-manager-unit-test for shorter name)

- **export NATIVE_COVERAGE=true**
- Add `native_coverage: true` to test module in Android.bp
- Go to: module-name/test
- Use mm or make command to build native binary
- Ex: For hardware/interfaces/automotive/vehicle/2.0/default/tests/  :
  mma or make vehicle-manager-unit-test -j32
- Copy coverage enabled instrumented binary to target
- `adb push out/target/product/product_name/data/nativetest64/vendor/vehicle-manager-unit-test /data/nativetest64/vehicle-manager-unit-test 
  adb shell chmod +x /data/nativetest64/vehicle-manager-unit-test`
- Run test cases and generate .gcda files

  `adb shell \
   GCOV_PREFIX=/data/local/tmp \
   GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP=echo $ANDROID_BUILD_TOP | grep -o / | wc -l \
   /data/nativetest64/vehicle-manager-unit-test`
- `adb shell find -iname *.gcda`
- `adb pull /data/local/tmp/proc/self/cwd/out/soong/.intermediates/hardware/interfaces/automotive/vehicle/2.0/default/vehicle-manager-unit-test/android_x86_64_silvermont_vendor_cov/obj/hardware/interfaces/automotive/vehicle/2.0/default/tests/ .(Destination folder)`
- Extract GCNO files from GCNODIR (archive file generated at
  out/overage/data/nativetest64/vendor/vehicle-manager-unit-test ) to
  same folder with GCDA files
- `llvm-cov gcov -f -b *.gcda` (https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-cov.html  )
- `lcov --directory . --base-directory . --gcov-tool /usr/bin/gcov-4.6 --capture -o cov.info` (http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php)
- `genhtml cov.info -o output`

[image: sample coverage report for vhal 2.0]
Here's the script which wraps all these commands:
https://gist.github.com/pankajgangwar/f070b8b54e83543f8e3638dcd2cae1b8

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://medium.com/@naveen.maltesh/generating-code-coverage-report-using-gnu-gcov-lcov-ee54a4de3f11) it is explaned how to generate coverage reports, which do require [GTest](https://github.com/google/googletest):

these [flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-coverage) enable the generation of test coverage: `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage`

then one has to use [gcov](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html): `gcov main_test.cpp`

which's output then can be passed on to [lcov](https://github.com/linux-test-project/lcov) (for [reference](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php)):

```
$ lcov --coverage --directory . --output-file main_coverage.info
```

from which one can generate an `lcov` coverage report in `HTML` format:

```
$ genhtml main_coverage.info --output-directory out
```

---

these [.gcda](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov-Data-Files.html) files in `.gcnodir` are `gcov` data files. `gcov` also has an output option `--json-format`, which might come handy when wanting to consume the coverage data with a web-service.

---

[one of the examples](http://logan.tw/posts/2015/04/28/check-code-coverage-with-clang-and-lcov/) from the links you've provided can be used to generate it for a whole project:

Collect the code coverage results:

```
$ lcov --directory . \
   --base-directory . \
   --gcov-tool gcov.sh \
   --capture -o cov.info
```

Generate HTML files:

```
$ genhtml cov.info -o output
```

where the only difference is, that the wrapper script would need to be adjusted to call `gcov`. probably one could even omit the wrapper passed with option `--gcov-tool`, since it should be directly called.

---

since one can only prepare the coverage report by adding the compiler flags, the `gcov` and `lcov` commands should be setup as post-build script, so that they would automatically generate the report.

Comment: Hi @Martin, thanks for your answer. I have already tried above solution, but never works with Android ecosystem. I need to know how to configure modules with Android.bp when building with AOSP and generate coverage from android device.